# apt-get failed to fork in UML (user mode Linux)

Tags: process, apt, user-mode-linux

I'm running a user mode Linux (Linux-3.19.8) for development testing.
I'd like to be able to edit files inside the UML. I have some experience with Vim, so I'd prefer that.
But unfortunately when I try installing Vim, this happens:

```
root@elk:/# apt-get install vim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libgpm2 vim-runtime
Suggested packages:
  gpm ctags vim-doc vim-scripts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgpm2 vim vim-runtime
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
FATAL -> Failed to fork.
```

I'm logged in as root on the UML, and clearly something happens before it fails.

I tried installing other things, and `apt -get remove` works fine but `apt -get install jed` produces output similar to that for Vim:

```
root@elk:/mnt/tmp# apt-get install jed
Reading package lists...Done
Building dependency tree... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
   jed-common libgpm2 libonig2 libpcre3 libpng12-0 libslang2-modules slsh
Suggested packages:
   gpm
The following NEW packages will be installed:
   jed jed-common libgpm2 libonig2 libpcre3 libpng12-0 libslang2-modules slsh
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
FATAL -> Failed to fork.
```

So clearly there is a problem, that isn't specific to Vim.

What could be the cause? Is there anything I can do to get Vim?

Comment: Does this happen with any package you try to install? What about actions other than installation?

Comment: Well, I know I can change permissions on files with chmod, navigate the filesystem with cd and rm files. I have not tried installing something else, do you have any suggestion as of what to try (won't have time until tomorrow to try, though)?

Comment: Note that if you want someone to be notified, in general you should put @ + username in front. And there are thousands of other packages you could install. But try an `apt-get remove` too. Examples of small packages that won't pull in much stuff and that you probably don't have installed include `jed`, `slrn`, and `mercurial`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Ok, so `apt -get remove` works but `apt -get install jed` doesn't, it gives: `root@elk:/mnt/tmp# apt-get install jed
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  jed-common libgpm2 libonig2 libpcre3 libpng12-0 libslang2-modules slsh
Suggested packages:
  gpm
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  jed jed-common libgpm2 libonig2 libpcre3 libpng12-0 libslang2-modules slsh
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
FATAL -> Failed to fork.
`

Comment: Ok, but put it in the question, not the comments, please. In any case, it is not specific to vim. I would not have expected it to be.